# Unable to read from server when writing is in progress

Tags: java, android

I am using an Async task to write a file to server.  This takes about 5 seconds usually.  There is a need to read from server in the meantime to populate a list in UI.  Is this possible?

At the moment, I am getting a blank screen until the previous write gets completed.  My read call is also Async.

Code to Write to server:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        int count = 0;
        try {
            String sourceFileUri = params[0];
            String mp4FilePath = params[1];
            String trimName = sourceFileUri.substring(0, sourceFileUri.length() - 4);

            File mp4_file = new File(mp4FilePath);
            String fileName_Time = mp4_file.getName();
            String trimTime = fileName_Time.substring(4);
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

            if (sourceFile.isFile()) {

                try {
                    int progress = 0;
                    String upLoadServerUri = "http://example.com/abc/efgh.php?";
                    // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                    URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
                    // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                    conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                    conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("bill", sourceFileUri);
                    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"bill\";filename=\"" + trimName + "_" + trimTime + "\"" + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    // create a buffer of maximum size
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                    // read file and write it into form...
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    while (bytesRead > 0) {
                        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        System.out.println("barbar "+bytesRead);
                        System.out.println("barbar "+bufferSize);
                        System.out.println("barbar "+bytesAvailable);
                        progress += ((bytesAvailable+5)/(bytesRead+1));
                        System.out.println("barbar prog "+progress);

                        // update progress bar
                        publishProgress((progress*10));
                    }

                    // send multipart form data necesssary after file
                    // data...
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                    // Responses from the server (code and message)
                    int serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                    String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                    if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                    }

                    // close the streams //
                    fileInputStream.close();
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // dialog.dismiss();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } // End else block

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // dialog.dismiss();

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Executed";
    }
```

Code to Read from server:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());

            reader = new BufferedReader(is);

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            return sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader!=null)
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: show how you use asynctask

Comment: It might also depend on your server - are you sure it allows the same client to read/write in parallel?

Comment: @GhostCat: Could you please let me know how to find out if the server allows the same client to read/write in parallel? Should i be reaching the customer support to get this info?

Comment: Lets put it that way: any decent product should allow you to do so. But honestly: how do you expect me to know how some 3rd party service works ... and you are not even telling us which service we are talking about? "Hello, doctor, my cat is making strange noises. Now it is making a different noise. Please tell me what's wrong now". Sorry, not possible.

Comment: @GhostCat: sorry about that, my bad.  I assumed there might be some general way to find it out, say by a ping or something.  I will check with my service provider.  thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If the "write" you're referring to is a complete rewrite of the file, then permitting this is fundamentally unsafe.  Consider using database technology for whatever it is you are keeping in ordinary files.  Database technology has been designed for more fine-grained granulation in the chunks of data that applications work with and henceforth, for better concurrency.

Comment: I am writing 1 mp4 file each time and the file size would be ~15MB.  I read through some basic Firebase articles initially to see if it will be a best fit.  But I couldn't really come to a conclusion at that time.